# C - having trouble using stat() to get bytes

Tags: c, stat

```
char string[50], s[50];
struct stat buf;
int counter = 0;

while (fgets(string, sizeof string, stdin)) {
    if (strspn(string, "size ") == 5) {
        for (int i = 5; i < strlen(string); i++) {
            s[counter] = string[i];
            counter++;
        }
        s[counter] = '\0';

        if (stat(s, &buf) < 0)
            return 1; //PROBLEM OCCURED

        printf("FILE: %s\n", s);
        printf("SIZE: %d\n", (int)buf.st_size);
    }
 }
```

The context of the program is not too important, but I am trying to use this because after "size " the name of the file is the only input. I then pass that into stat which is supposed to give me bytes of the given file if it exists. Ultimately, the program returns 1 every time like I am using stat wrong. Help please!

Comment: What does `s` contain right before the `stat` call?

Comment: `strspn` doesn't do what you think. Use `strstr` instead.

Comment: I don't think that is a problem. I am looking for "size " and when that occurs I am getting the input thereafter. It may not be the best, but it is working for other functions I have going.

Comment: You should consider replacing `return 1` with something like `perror("stat"); return 1;` (or hidden behind whatever `#ifdef DEBUG` you may wish..) to give you a useful error message to debug with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fgets() returns the trailing newline character(s), so your 'filename' is never correct.

Replace:

```
for(int i = 5; i < strlen(string); i++) {
   s[counter] = string[i];
   counter++;
}
s[counter] = '\0';
```

with:

```
char *source = &(string[5]), *dest = s;
while((*source != 0) && (*source != 10) && (*source != 13)) {
   *dest++ = *source++;
}
*dest = 0;
```

This way you are copying everything until a zero (end of string), or carriage return, or linefeed - rather than appending the CR and/or LF char to the string too.

Comment: .. what happens if the filename actually contains a CR or LF character?

Comment: Then you should consider a better file naming convention :-P

Answer (score 0):

I guess the underlying problem exists in the usage of strspn(). The return value of strspn() can be determined from

> if all of the characters in str1 are in str2, the function returns the
>   length of the entire str1 string, and if the first character in str1
>   is not in str2, the function returns zero.

You can check the source string whether it contains the compared value of "size " or not.

[reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strspn/).